# Easily duplicate bug fixes in an old svn repository into the new git repositories.

Tags: git, svn, interop

We have moved most of our codebase from a monolithic `svn` repository into a set of `git` repositories. For various reasons, some work (on old versions of the project deployed in the field) has to continue in old `svn` branches, after they have been moved to `git` and deleted from the subversion `trunk`.

I have just done some work like this on an `svn` branch and re-applied the changes from the `svn` repository into the `git` repositories by doing the following:

```
cd <common_svn_commit_root>
svn diff -r 12344:12345 > ~/r12345.diff
gedit ~/r12345.diff
cd <common_git_commit_root>
git apply ~/r12345.diff
```

but it is rather cumbersome to do this for each and every `svn` commit, especially the `gedit` step, where I have to manually munge the `svn` paths into `git` paths (usually by prefixing the top level directory name).

One problem with trying some of the options presented so far is that the structure of the old `svn` repo and the new `git` repo are different. This is one of the reasons I have to edit the patch file.

The old directory structure was

```
svn
    configurations
        blah
        mine
        blam
    plugins
        foo
        core
        mine
        bar
```

Whereas the new structure is

```
svn
    plugins
        bar
git
    my_git
        my_config
        plugins
            mine
    core_git
        plugins
            core
    foo_git
        plugins
            foo
```

I would really like to know if there is an easier way to do this, and understand what the best practice is for this situation.

Comment: "Unfortunately svn diff -r 12345:12346 doesn't seem to support (at 1.6.5) generating a diff off all files which have changed in that commit." - it should do, if run on the repository or the root of the checkout, except perhaps added and removed files. What's wrong with the diff?

Comment: @Rup - Thanks, just knowing that the `svn diff` *should* work as I expected was enough to help me get that part to work. Removing that issue though widens the question to ask if there is a better solution than this.

Comment: SVN 1.7 supports diffs in Git format (--git option); maybe it would help

Comment: Thanks @DmitryPavlenko but I've already solved the `svn diff` problem and updated my question to remove mention of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the directory structure of your sources kept the same, I suggest that you add a remote to your old SVN branch :

```
$ git config --add svn-remote.svn-branch.url http://my.svn.server/project/branches/my-branch
$ git config --add svn-remote.svn-branch.fetch :refs/remotes/old-svn-branch
```

This way, you will be able to track changes on both old SVN branches, and your brand new Git server in local branches, and use [git-cherry-pick](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) to apply the commits containing the fixes on your Git server branches.

EDIT

Git keeps track of the file moves.

I did not try it myself, but if you clone the SVN repo, then locally move the directories to match you new Git server structure, cherry-pick merges could apply it on the moved files.

It already worked for me for some files, but maybe there's some limitations. It definitely is worth the try.

Comment: I'll have to look into `git` svn remote branches. Your answer may not be a full solution, but it could point me in useful directions. I've added some information to my question about why this isn't *directly* relevant to my situation.

Comment: related to file moves: if you move a lot of files I recommend to increase the file move detection limit of git:

git config --global diff.renameLimit 10000

Answer (score 2):

you can use git svn to synchronize your git repo with the changes from svn.

```
git svn --authors-file=authors.txt clone https://repo/svn/reponame/trunk reponame-git-svn

# if something aborts:
cd reponame-git-svn
git svn fetch

# create a new branch
git checkout -b dvcs

git remote add dvcs-svn https://repo/git/reponame.git
```

this will leave you with the svn sources in a git branch. To sync from svn to git:

```
git checkout master
# get the changes from svn
git svn rebase
git checkout dvcs

# apply the changes from svn
git rebase master

# fetch the changes from git repo to the local repo
git fetch dvcs-svn

# apply the changes from git repo to the branch dvcs
git rebase dvcs-svn/master

# push all changes back to git repo
git push dvcs-svn dvcs:master
```

we have better experience with rebase than with merge. Hopefully this does the job for you as well.

Comment: How do you get this to work when the structure of the `svn` repository is different to the directory structure of the `git` repositories? This is why I currently have to manually edit my patches to adjust the paths.

Comment: well at some point the structure should be the same?
the git clone command above retrieves the /trunk folder only. So that would be the SVN path that is common between svn and git.
If the file structure changed through moving files around in git only it may be difficult to sync the changes in git too. But since the move is tracked by git it may also work - I've never tested that. A similar structure definitely helps here.

Comment: this sounds like your a bit doomed?
What about cloning the svn repo into an own git repo, keeping the structure from svn and using the diff/patch approach to move patches from "git-svn-mirror" to "git-migrated"? then use git-svn to push the changes back to svn.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing forbids you having `git` and `svn` coexist in the source tree. This makes the picking of commits much easier than patching and copying between different source trees.

1. `svn checkout` a branch and revision you have already in git.
2. `git clone` and `git checkout` the same source tree state as in step 1 (there could be short cut here involving bare repositories if the repository is very very huge - you only need the `.git/` repository data).
3. Copy the `.git/` directory into your svn checkout root directory.
4. Tell `git` to ignore subversion meta data by adding `.svn` into your `.gitignore` file.
5. If you can, you can also run `svn propset svn:ignore dirname .git` to tell `svn` ignore  .git director.

Now there are many methods to export the commits. Here's one method if you want to pick up say commit `r12345` (assuming a point as above where svn and git both are up-to-date):

1. create and checkout temporary git branch (`git checkout -b throway-branch`);
2. get one below the desired svn commit by `svn co -r12344`;
3. commit these changes (to be ignored) into your `git` repository by something like `git add -A` followed by `git commit -m "SVN -r12344 (uninteresting stuff)"`;
4. checkout the interesting svn commit by `svn co -r12345` and
5. save it to your git repository: `git add -A && git commit --date <svn commit date>` 
   (using here `--date <svn commit date>` assuming you want to keep the svn commit date).
6. Now you can `git cherry-pick` this last meaningful commit to your actual branch you plan of publishing to the world.

This kind of dual repository setup worked for me quite well when I once had to deal with upstream subversion repository while using `git` locally. I ended up making some scripts to make all this easier. E.g. for you, a script could pick up the svn commit date and message and create a git commit for you with the same date and message (with svn revision number added to the message for matching up with the svn commit).

Alternatively you can just use `svn diff --git` and `git am` like you mention in your post, which is much more convenient because you do not need to move the patches between different directories and you can always compare your single working directory with your `svn checkout` and current `git commit` at any time.

I am not familiar with `git svn` to know if this would be useful tool for you.

Comment: Thanks FooF - Interesting approach. It seems like it might be even more steps to do it this way than the workflow I'm using at the moment though, and if I was going to go to the trouble of scripting this, I could script the export/munge/import diff workflow too. Out of interest, when working with an upstream svn repo, why did you not use `git-svn`? It sounds to me like it was the situation `git-svn` was designed for.

Comment: Just the preparation needs some steps with the dual repository approach. If you do not have lot of branches to deal with it is not complicated. For me it was a big win not to have to deal with two separate work directories and have the repositories in sync in one place. There is a lot of flexibility how you can export the changes to `git`. I recall the main use for my scripts was to actually cache the svn meta directories in another location because of the slowness of subversion over the internet.

Comment: I had read somewhere that `git-svn` was not entirely reliable in certain situations; maybe I overreacted and did not research very much then about the suitability. Also my need was just to track my local changes I personally made based on some fixed tags - sometimes just getting the svn trunk changes to my upstream following git branch. Afterwards I just needed to have the svn trunk checked out and ignored by git. If you *need to commit to svn*, or are using svn *properties* or relying in having *empty directories*, maybe `git-svn` is the way to go in that case.